# Switching a current source with a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, switches, current-source

Probably is basic electronics, nonetheless every time there is an explanation of using a MOSFET as a switch (both NMOS or PMOS) it is always with a DC source. However, what if I want to drive a LED matrix where the resistances changes?

I know that, if there is an open circuit with a current source, in an ideal case voltage would increase to infinite and there will be an arc to close the circuit. but I can't see how that might affect the circuit.

Here is more or less the idea.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo7K0a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If I1 is truly an ideal current source then it will drive that current through the MOSFET irrespective of what the gate voltage is set to. The LED will remain lit always. If it's a non-ideal current source then you need to provide details.

Comment: The only thing wrong with this circuit is current source connected to the ground instead of power source, IMHO. After all, the best even ideal current source can do is turn itself into ideal conductor. But with FET open the bottom part of a circuit essentially does not exist, so that ideal conductor will be just hanging "in the air" so to speak. Regardless of FET leakage, by the way.

Comment: Just to spell it out, if the current source can produce a voltage higher than (5V + Vgs_off), the P-mos won't be turning off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circuit is fundamentally incorrect. The current produced by an (ideal) current source cannot be stopped by a series-connected switch; *it must be diverted by a switch connected in parallel* to the load (this is the so-called "current steering" technique). The reason for this is, as stated in the comments, that the current source will "try" with all its might to pass the current through the load. So, we can formulate another circuit "golden rule":

**The current can not be stopped; it can be only diverted.**

A typical example of this technique is the so-called ["flyback diode"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/473658/61398) connected in parallel to an inductor switched by a transistor. The transistor switch cannot (safely) stop the current produced by the inductor (acting as a very good current source) since it is connected in series. So, when it opens (cut off), the diode switch closes thus short connecting the inductor... and the current is diverted through the dioge.

Another solution can be to modify the OP's circuit so that the MOSFET acts as a *controlled current source*. For this purpose, just move the LED to the place of I1 and set the desired current by R1.

Comment: I might be wrong, but when the circuit is open (by FET switch) then current source will not "try" anything, it will be an inactive branch of a circuit. I am talking about real devices, of course, not ideal ones. Something like LM134 series. Of course current can be stopped. Just remove the wires :)

Comment: @Maple, A relevant comment... To answer it, we should consider [how current sources are implemented](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/279592) and what they would "try" to do when the circuit is open to keep up the current. The most dangerous case is when the current source begins increasing its internal voltage with the "hope" to restore the current. A typical case is the inductor (e.g., in the car ignition system). But the current source can "try" to keep the current by decreasing its dynamic internal resistance up to zero. In this case there is no problem; it becomes a voltage source.

Comment: @Maple, The real current source is a devilishly cunning device:) - if you try to "remove the wire", it will try to connect it through an arc (this is what the OP also noticed). Have you read the safety instruction about how to demount a current transformer? I have read it - you must first short the current coil and only then disconnect it from the circuit...

Comment: The so called "floating current sources" are just simple transistors with current feedback, nothing devilish or cunning about them. Many datasheets have inner schematics, look for example at [this one](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lm234.pdf). No coils here, So the best they can do, as you mentioned yourself, is to pretend to be a simple conductor. Their ability to create an arc is no different from the mechanical switch, i.e. it depends entirely on available voltage. Furthermore, if you use FET as a switch even that is not a problem, with properly rated FET.

Comment: A constant current source (CCS) is a device/circuit that produces a constant value of current regardless of source voltage or load resistance. The output voltage will continue to rise until it approaches the supply voltage -circuit voltage drop, never exceed it. A constant current circuit can also be used as a current limiter. The opposite is a constant current sink, the circuit is simply inverted. Power the leds with a CCS and switch them with a N-Channel MOSFET. If yo u do this with an inductive load just the proper avalanche rated MOSFET.

Comment: @Maple and Gil, Interesting topic... if only we do not oppose the concepts to their implementations. In my answer, I meant the concept of "ideal current source" as we know it from theoretical electrical engineering... and I illustrated it with one of its very good electrical implementations - the inductor. It can be considered as ideal because it manages to pass its current through the load no matter how high the voltage across it is (ie, it has infinitely high "compliance voltage"). However, this is not always necessary but is accompanied by great losses and is dangerous for our lives...

Comment: In electronics, we are more practical and also make "ideal" current sources which precisely keep up their current through the load but only in a limited range of the voltage across the load (ie, they have low "compliance voltage"). We build  them without negative feedback by making either the voltage or current "dynamic"... or,  more frequently, by the help of negative feedback. So, the value of the compliance voltage is the difference between the "electrical ideal current source" and the "electronic idealized current source"...

Comment: … and the first will be ever ideal while the second only in a limited range determined by the supply voltage. I highly recommend to you [my paper about the philosophy of creating current sources](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/279592).

Comment: @Gil, Look at my comments above...